# Apache rewrite conditions not catching existing directories or files

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/board/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]*).* /board/index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/board/user/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]*).* /board/user/index.php?$1 [L]
```

I am trying to forward **mydomain.com/board/something** to **mydomain.com/board/index.php?something** and **/board/user/something** to **/board/user/index.php?something**. And have it not rewrite existing files or directories.

The board/ one works but it fires even if i request an existing directory so I can't test the second one. Also a page like mydomain.com/board/signup/index.php is forwarding to /board/index.php?signup

These are all within a `<VirtualHost *:443>` and my VPS is actually handling a few different domain names on the same instance if that makes a difference.

I found similar issues in search but their solution was what I am using above already.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently on Apache 2.4 (maybe 2.2 and above?) you have to do it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

However this does not catch if you navigate to, say, mydomain.com/board/ when there is an index.php there. So this is what I have come up with, finally.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !index\.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/board/$1/index.php !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/board/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\.]*) /board/index.php?$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !index\.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/board/user/$1/index.php !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/board/user/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\.]*) /board/user/index.php?$1 [L]
```